# C# class not public

Tags: c#, class, object, public

I am trying to make a class so when I do the following inside a file:

```
Functions LoginFunctions = new Functions();
LoginFunctions.loadFunctions();
```

It will create my object which I need, and make it public so every form which calls the class will be able to use it. The class file is below.

```
namespace App
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public void loadFunctions()
        {
            TaskbarItemInfo taskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();

        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be making the taskbarItemInfo object public, and it is not letting me use it anywhere else other then inside the class. How do I make it public so every file that calls the class can use the object?

Comment: Looks more like this should be a static class, with static methods

Comment: Huh? Are you trying to return a `TaskbarItemInfo` isntance or creating a static class? `TaskbarItemInfo loadFunctions() {...}` or `List<object> loadFunctions() {...}`, `public TaskbarItemInfo myTaskbarItemInfo;` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, make it a property, for example like so:

```
public class Functions
{
    public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; private set; }

    public void loadFunctions()
    {
        this.TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your taskbaritem class is in the scope of the method and therefore you wont be able to access it outsite of the class.

Create a public property or return it in the method.

```
    namespace App
    {
        public class Functions
        {
            private TaskbarItemInfo _taskbarItemInfo;

            public TaskbarItemInfo taskbarItemInfo
           {
               get
              {
                   return _taskbarItemInfo;
              }
           }

            public void loadFunctions()
            {
                _taskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();

            }
        }
    }
```

I would also go and change the loadFunctions method to a constructor which creates all the objects you need.

```
public Functions()
{
    _taskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
}
```

Comment: This is *not* a property but a public *field*! Properties would be the way to go here.

Comment: You could just use `public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; protected set; }`.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you provide, `taskbarItemInfo` is declared within the local scope of the `loadFunctions()` method. If you want it to be public for some class, you must make it a class member before you can make it public.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the variable public.

```
namespace App
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; private set; }

        public void loadFunctions()
        {
            TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: You could also do the initialization of the items in the constructor.

```
namespace App
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public TaskbarItemInfo TaskbarItemInfo { get; private set; }

        public Functions() 
        {
            loadFunctions();
        }

        private void loadFunctions()
        {
            TaskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you don't need the `LoginFunctions.loadFunctions();` line of code after you initialize your LoginFunctions object.

Comment: Please don't. Use properties!

Comment: 0xA3, I'm not questioning you, but why use properties instead of a public variable?  Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend you Jon's article on the matter: [Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx). It might not be relevant for the sample given by the OP, but after all we should be teaching best practices here :-)

Comment: @0xA3, fixed... should have wrote it like that in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to access it as a property which generates a private static member when needed.

```
namespace App
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private static TaskbarItemInfo _taskbarItemInfo;

        public static TaskbarItemInfo TaskBarItemInfoProperty
        {
            get{
               if (_taskbarItemInfo == null) 
               {
                  _taskbarItemInfo = new TaskbarItemInfo();
               }
               return _taskbarItemInfo;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void testFunction()
        {
           Functions.TaskBarItemInfoProperty.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```